# Extract a section of many objects in an array

Tags: javascript

If I have array of objects like this

```
[
    {
        "name" : "some name",
        "more data" : "data",
        ...
    },
    {
        "name" : "another name",
        "more data" : "data",
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

And I want to copy the array, but only the name element in the object so that I have this:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "some name",
    },
    {
        "name" : "another name",
    },
    ...
]
```

Is there a short hand way to do this without writing a loop?

Comment: This is the third question in as many days on javascript array of objects where the OP specified "I dont want to use loops". Whats up with that? Why is looping over an array seen as such a problem?

Comment: @Jamiec I'm just trying to learn how to make my code both compact and readable, having loops everywhere doesn't count. Also, before I abstract the logic I wanted to be sure there wasn't a built in way of dealing with this.

Comment: If you want to process a set of elements, you always have to loop at some level.

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to do this with a loop, but in can still be short:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = {name: arr[i].name};
```

If you use any sort of framework or library all it will do is hide the loop from you. It will still loop through everything.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/FSnAM/)

Comment: You could also use `arr.map(…)` or `arr.forEach(…)` which are also just loops that are hidden away, but built into the language - if the browser supports it, that is - rather than in a library. But yes, either way, somewhere, somehow you need a loop if you're doing something with an array

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way of doing this without a loop. Can I suggest you do this with a bit of prototyping magic. (Note, this can be done with some `map` or `forEach` magic which just hides away the fact that you're looping. I'll leave this with the loop to illustrate the idea)

```
Array.prototype.clone = function(predicate)
{
   var newArray = [];
   for(var i = 0;i <this.length; i++){
       var newElement = {};
       for(x in this[i]){
           if(predicate(x)){
              newElement[x] = this[i][x];
          }
       }
      newArray.push(newElement);
   }
    return newArray;
}
```

This allows you to clone an array, passing in a function that decides which property to keep from each element in the array. So given an array like:

```
var arr = [
    {
        "name" : "some name",
        "more data" : "data"
    },
    {
        "name" : "another name",
        "more data" : "data"
    }
];
```

You can do

```
var newArray = arr.clone(function(x){ return x == "name";});
```

Which will return you an array with the same number of objects, but each object will just have the `name` element.

Live example:  http://jsfiddle.net/8BGmG/